# Using anchor ^ pattern when using less / search command

Tags: man, search, less, pattern-matching

When navigating through Linux man pages, sometimes you need to query the meaning of flags like `-p` or `-al` in the man pages.

The default text reader for man pages is less and I'm trying to use the / search to find the first occurrence from the commons flag list definitions using:

```
/^-p
```

But `Pattern not found` happen and not works.

This trick works when working in vim, but not applicable in less when reading the man pages.

Is there a way to accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/^-p` means there are no characters before `-p`. But if you look at the man pages, you will see there are some blank characters preceding these flags.

**The search pattern should be `/^\s+-p`**

where:

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `\s+` matches one or more occurrences of whitespace characters

---

*Edit: While the search pattern above is ideal, it is not very practical when searching. An easy way to find such sections in man pages is to use `/  -p`. Slash, followed by 2 spaces and the option your are searching for.*